# jQuery .animate() causing a pause

Tags: jquery, methods

I have a question about the .animate() and .stop() jQuery methods I was hoping someone could help explain.

I had smooth scroll on my website but I was having an issue when I clicked the button to scroll down, there would be a pause before it let me scroll back up or down again, I couldn't do it right away. I added .stop() in front of .animate() and it completely fixed the problem - I can click the button to scroll down and then immediately scroll up or down with no pause, and I'm not entirely clear on why this solved the problem.

Would someone explain to me why this is?

This is an example of my code:

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
if(windowWidth > 800) {
    $(function() {
        $("a[href*='#'][href!='#']").click(function() {
            $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html,body').stop().animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 500);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
}

var jump=function(e) {
   if (e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var target = $(this).attr("href");
   } else{
       var target = location.hash;
   } 

   $('html,body').stop().animate({
       scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
   }, 500, function(){
       location.hash = target;
   });
}
```

Comment: Animations queue up with jQuery, so a running animation has to complete before the next one has to start.  By telling it to `stop()` you're basically telling it to stop what it's doing and start a new animation.  They both have their time and place.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to demonstrate this is to change your animate time to something longer, eg from 500 to `5000`.

When you call `.animate()` it gets added to a queue and will proceed when that queue has completed. eg:

```
$("div").animate({scrollTop:1000}, 5000).animate({scrollTop:0}, 5000);
```

will take 5s to scroll down and then 5s to scroll up - ie the second `.animate` waits for the first.

This is noticeable if your animates are called from button clicks and haven't completed - ie queues the click's animate.

When you use `.stop` (https://api.jquery.com/stop/) it cancels the currently queued `.animate` and adds your new one to the queue - this distinction is important if you have multiple animates queued, but in your case there's only ever one animate as you cancel the previous one before starting a new one. So:

```
$("div").animate({scrollTop:1000}, 5000)
        .stop()
        .animate({scrollTop:0}, 5000);
```

will never scroll to 1000 as that will be cancelled by the `.stop`.